# Crash when starting activity on certain devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I just released an alarm app and it's been hell. It's breaking on certain devices when they try to open up the alarm list screen. I have no idea why it's breaking on some devices and not others. Every phone I've seen it tried on it works perfectly, but opening up the alarm list on some other devices blows it up. I'm really out of my depth for this kind of specific device compatibility issue.

The code at AlarmClock line 227 is this:

```
 View changeSettings = findViewById(R.id.alarm_settings);
        changeSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class));
                }
            });
```

And it references this line of xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/alarm_settings"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/menu_settings"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />
```

This links to a settings activity I borrowed the source of from an adapted version of the android stock alarm, but it uses addPreferencesFromResource which is allegedly deprecated. Is that what's causing this problem?

This is the stack trace from the user's device:

Nexus 7
Touched setup alarm button and then it crashed

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nathantempelman.GoodMorningAlarmFree/com.nathantempelman.alarmclockfree.AlarmClock}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.nathantempelman.alarmclockfree.AlarmClock.updateLayout(AlarmClock.java:227)
at com.nathantempelman.alarmclockfree.AlarmClock.onCreate(AlarmClock.java:210)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
... 11 more
```

Any help would be splendiferous. I know that it's happened on someone else's tablet as well, not sure if it's a tablet issue.
The app is here if anyone wants to give it a test: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nathantempelman.GoodMorningAlarmFree

Comment: Your stack trace indicates the problem arises in your updateLayout method, AlarmClock.java:227.

Comment: As you can see, the issue is a `NullPointerException` in AlarmClock.java, on line 227, in method `updateLayout(..)`. Basically, you're trying to do something with an object that is null. If you have different tablet/phone layouts, then I'd guess and say you're trying to do something with a View which doesn't exist in the tablet layout.

Comment: I haven't specified a tablet specific layout, it's the same for all devices. The layout in question is a list of alarms, does that kind of view not exist on tablets? I had hoped it would just work like a giant phone, and that bigger would just be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a NullPointerException in your AlarmClock class in updateLayout method in line 227 :)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.nathantempelman.alarmclockfree.AlarmClock.updateLayout(AlarmClock.java:227)
 at com.nathantempelman.alarmclockfree.AlarmClock.onCreate(AlarmClock.java:210)
```

i would check that code first.

as you didn't post any code, i cant help more at the moment :)

Comment: Aha, wow sorry. I looked at the first six lines and was entirely flummoxed, and had to go to work. I'll find the code for that when I get home. Thanks :)

Comment: For most Exceptions in Android (maybe even Java at all?) it's a good idea to check if there is a "Caused by"-Exception. I learned that the hard way too :D

Comment: I added the code, still no idea what to do about it. Any idea?

Comment: well currently, the only possible reason i see is that it cant find the `R.id.alarm_settings` view. then the  _changeSettings.setOnClickListener_ would raise the Exception.

do you maybe have some alternative layouts for screen sizes, android versions or whatever what applies for Nexus7 Tablet but is missing the button?

Comment: You know, that might make sense. I will have a look when I get home. I hadn't actually checked for alternative layouts in the source that I borrowed, just assumed that all the layouts were under layouts. Where would alternative layouts live, do you know?

Comment: all layouts are in res/layout or folders like res/layout-_XXX_ where _XXX_ are qualifiers that android uses to find the best matching resource for the current device. You can find more Informations about those qualifiers [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a tablet to test on, but I think I've fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else stumbles across this, the problem in the end was that there was a separate layout file for tablets which I hadn't seen in the source codebase I borrowed for a part of my application. I had obviously added a bunch of functionality, but hadn't updated the tablet layout. The buttons to access the things I had added weren't in the tablet layout file. Ergo, null pointer exception only when a tablet device loaded the tablet layout file and searched for non existent objects in the display. When I deleted that file, everything worked perfectly.

I know, hurp and or durp. But maybe someone has the same problem and might want to check for this.